# Without using loops, read the first 9 digits of an ISBN-10 as a string and calculate the 10th digit

Tags: c++, string

I am missing something from the chapters; I've read them front and back but I think I need some sort of general guidance.

Not allowed to use `loops` and I've read through the [JAVA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39479251/java-isbn-10-number-find-10th-digit) and through the [Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/974952/split-an-integer-into-digits-to-compute-an-isbn-checksum) examples.

I'm supposed to modify my first (top) code to use a string input using `getline` then calculate the last digit of an ISBN-10.

With an input of `013601267`, I'm not sure why my output is `5` after the checksum for the 10th digit in my modified code. The value should be `1`.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
  cout
  << "Enter the first nine digits as integerss of an ISBN.."
  <<endl;
  int d1, d2, d3, d4, d5, d6, d7, d8, d9;
  int d10;
  cin
  >> d1
  >> d2
  >> d3
  >> d4
  >> d5
  >> d6
  >> d7
  >> d8
  >> d9;
  d10 = ( d1 * 1 + d2 * 2 + d3 * 3 + d4 * 4 + d5 * 5 + d6 * 6 + d7 * 7 + d8 * 8 + d9 * 9 ) % 11;
  if ( d10 > 9)
  {
    cout
    << "d10: "
    << d10
    << endl
    <<"The corresponding ISBN-10 is... "
    << d1
    << d2
    << d3
    << d4
    << d5
    << d6
    << d7
    << d8
    << d9
    << 'X'
    << endl;
  }
  else
  {
    cout
    << "d10: "
    << d10
    << endl
    <<"The corresponding ISBN-10 is... "
    << d1
    << d2
    << d3
    << d4
    << d5
    << d6
    << d7
    << d8
    << d9
    << d10
    <<endl;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Below is modified code and If I'm successful I'm going to concatenate ISBN to d10 but I've left them separate as I was trying to see what the values of the math'd index elements were.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cmath>


using namespace std;

int main()
{
  cout
  << "Enter the first nine digits of an ISBN-10..."
  << endl;
  string ISBN;
  getline(cin, ISBN, '\n');

  int d10 = ( ISBN[0] * 1 + ISBN[1] * 2 + ISBN[2] * 3 + ISBN[3] * 4 + ISBN[4] * 5 + ISBN[5] * 6 + ISBN[6] * 7 + ISBN[7] * 8 + ISBN[8] * 9 ) % 11;


  cout

  << d10
  << endl
  << ISBN
  << endl;

  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`std::string` is an array of **characters** not integers. and in c++ `'1'` is not equal to `1`.

What you are doing is adding characters ascii codes. what you need to do is change `d10` calculation like this :

```
int d10 = ( (ISBN[0] - '0') * 1 + (ISBN[1] - '0') * 2 + (ISBN[2] - '0') * 3 + (ISBN[3] - '0') * 4 + (ISBN[4] - '0') * 5
 + (ISBN[5] - '0') * 6 + (ISBN[6] - '0') * 7 + (ISBN[7] - '0') * 8 + (ISBN[8] - '0') * 9 ) % 11;
```

To convert character to actual integer value (I mean `'1' -> 1`) you need to do something like this :

```
char a = '1';
int ia = a - '0'; //ia == 1
```

Comment: Thanks Hamed! It makes sense now. Now to concatenate all I have to do is add the '0' to get the char and append it to the string. I did ISBN+= d10 + '0'.

Comment: @LuigiCampbell Depends on what you need, if you want `1` to be `'1'` yes `+ '0'` is a way but if you want `13601267` to be `"13601267"` you can't simple add `'0'` to it. in this case you can use   [`std::to_string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/to_string).

Comment: Yeah, to convert the integer into a string to concatenate the two elements. I just wanted to use a conditional expression to print  out any mod higher than 9 as an X. I did eventually run into this problem on another task but `std:: to_string` made it easier. Thank you!